# Windows Message Received Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, windows-messages

I have a Windows Message Receive Method Below:

```
protected override void WndProc ( ref Message message )
{
    if ( // some analytic logic  )
    {
        if ( OnCmdReceived != null )
            OnCmdReceived.Invoke ( message );
    }
    else
        base.WndProc ( ref message );
}
```

The OnCmdReceived with invoke Method is :

```
static object _locker = new object( );
private void processCmdReceived ( Message message )
{
    lock ( _locker )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( $"Current Thread ID : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}" );        
    }
}
```

The Result show not only one Messagebox show on the screen, even if I didn't click OK on previous MessageBox. All MessageBox's ManagedThread ID are the same as 1.

As I know, if there are only one thread in WndProc, next received message will wait for Clicking OK and come in. Or if there is a mutiThread scenario, the next  one will also wait in `_locker` until the previous thread finish its work. But in this case, the Managed ID should not be the same.

How could it happen? Did I miss something?

Note : I have Checked that I added `processCmdReceived` method to `OnCmdReceived event` only one time.

Comment: A window gets a lot of messages, most of which are handled by the default window procedure.  Using MessageBox.Show() is the worst possible way to debug in general, it gets particularly out of hand in this case.  Use Debug.Print() instead.  Using *lock* or Invoke() does not make sense, a window is expected to receive all of its messages on the thread that owns it and if it doesn't then you have a very nasty bug that you must never hide..

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your reply. I will check those out.

Comment: @user1377273 `MessageBox.Show()` will display messagebox however, it won't freeze UI Thread, i.e. `WndProc` will be called even if message is shown, if all conditions match, event will be invoked, therefore messagebox will be shown. What you can do is to have a flag and don't fire event/MessageBox.Show, when it's already opened.

Comment: @HansPassant why in this case, the lock doesn't work and allows multiple messagebox to show even they are not closed? MessageBox.Show should block the current thread until it closes.

Comment: @Leri Thank you. In this case, could ManagedThread ID represent itself ? how could all threadID to be the same, if I didn't click ok, processCmdReceived won't run next step. Am I right?

Comment: Lock is re-entrant on the same thread.  Which is a good thing, if it weren't then your program would have deadlocked.